# Recursive shell script to list files

Tags: shell, directory

I'm trying to write a shell script that lists certain types of files in a Directory (and sub-directories).  I'm struggling with the recursive part.

Here's what I have:

```
#!/bin/sh

#download dir
DOWNLOADING_DIR=/Users/richard/Downloads

echo "Starting Script..."

for FILE in $DOWNLOADING_DIR/*
do
    if [ -d "$FILE" ]
    then
        echo "...Checking Directory "$FILE
        for DFILE in $FILE/*
        do
            echo "Found file ... $DFILE"
        done
    else
        echo "Found file ... $FILE"
        echo ""
    fi
done
```

The problem is when it finds the directory, it doesn't find any names of files in the directory. It just lists the sub-directory name and not the files in the sub. It works for the files in the first directory.

I need this script to search out .txt or .doc files and move them to another directory.

Comment: I would suggest that you can probably do this with "find" and "dirname" and maybe "cut" depending on what exactly your goal is.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your script is *not* recursive, as it does not call itself.

Here is a variation that implements something like what you have recursively:

```
#!/bin/bash

walk_dir () {
    shopt -s nullglob dotglob

    for pathname in "$1"/*; do
        if [ -d "$pathname" ]; then
            walk_dir "$pathname"
        else
            printf '%s\n' "$pathname"
        fi
    done
}

DOWNLOADING_DIR=/Users/richard/Downloads

walk_dir "$DOWNLOADING_DIR"
```

The function `walk_dir` takes a directory pathname as its only argument and iterates over its content.  If a directory is found, it calls itself recursively to traverse that sub-directory.

Modifying this to find the files whose filename suffix is either `.txt` or `.doc`:

```
#!/bin/bash

walk_dir () {    
    shopt -s nullglob dotglob

    for pathname in "$1"/*; do
        if [ -d "$pathname" ]; then
            walk_dir "$pathname"
        else
            case "$pathname" in
                *.txt|*.doc)
                    printf '%s\n' "$pathname"
            esac
        fi
    done
}

DOWNLOADING_DIR=/Users/richard/Downloads

walk_dir "$DOWNLOADING_DIR"
```

Note that by "file" above we really mean anything that is not a directory or a symbolic link to a directory, which may not be the same as a *regular file*.  By setting the `dotglob` and `nullglob` shell options in `bash`, we are able to find hidden pathnames and will not have to test specially for possibly empty directories.

A variation for `/bin/sh` that does not care about hidden names:

```
#!/bin/sh

walk_dir () {
    for pathname in "$1"/*; do
        if [ -d "$pathname" ]; then
            walk_dir "$pathname"
        elif [ -e "$pathname" ]; then
            case "$pathname" in
                *.txt|*.doc)
                    printf '%s\n' "$pathname"
            esac
        fi
    done
}

DOWNLOADING_DIR=/Users/richard/Downloads

walk_dir "$DOWNLOADING_DIR"
```

With the `globstar` and `exglob` shell options in `bash`, one could even do the following (with no recursion) to move the files:

```
shopt -s globstar extglob

mv "$DOWNLOADING_DIR"/**/*.@(txt|doc) "$destdir"
```

... unless the resulting file list turned out to be too long.  The `**` matches across slashes in pathnames (enabled by `globstar`) and `*.@(txt|doc)` matches any filename that ends with either `.txt` or `.doc` (enabled by `extglob`).

---

A far more efficient and portable way to find regular files with a filename suffix of either `.txt` or `.doc` in or under some top-level directory `$topdir`, and to move them to some other directory `$destdir`:

```
find "$topdir" -type f \( -name '*.txt' -o -name '*.doc' \) \
    -exec mv {} "$destdir" \;
```

With GNU `mv` you can make it a bit more efficient,

```
find "$topdir" -type f \( -name '*.txt' -o -name '*.doc' \) \
    -exec mv -t "$destdir" {} +
```

This variation would move *batches* of files instead of one file at a time.  Use `mv` with `-v` to see what gets moved, or add `-print` before `-exec` to get a listing of the pathnames that `mv` is called with.

Comment: I think I'll go toward the efficient route as you said.. and look into find instead of the loops.

Comment: 'find "$DOWNLOADING_DIR" -type f \( -name '*.tex' -o -name '*.doc' -o -name '*.txt' \) \
    -exec mv -v {} "$COMPLETED_DIR" \;'

Is what I went with. It works well.

@Kusalananda, But another question, if I may.  

How does one skip moving a file.. Like if the file contains with file name "sample", is it possible to skip moving that file to the new directory?

Comment: @Borg357 Just before `-exec`, or just after `-type f`, add `! -name '*sample*'`.  That will skip files whose filename contains the string `sample`.

Comment: @Borg357 Also note that the parentheses need to be escaped (they weren't in your comment).

Comment: `find "$DOWNLOADING_DIR" -type f \( -name '*.tct' -o -name '*.txt' -o -name '*.doc' \) \
    ! -name '*sample*' -exec mv -v {} "$COMPLETED_DIR" \;`

Thanks

Comment: `! -name '*sample*'` doesn't seem to do anything.  do I need to place the escape before?  @Kusalananda